# Unclear Android Current Location Retrieval Tutorial

Tags: android

I am recycling the code provided to check that the user's device has Google Play services on it before acquiring location data from http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. When copy-pasting it into my IDE, Eclipse correctly points out errors in lines, because "connectionResult" has never been defined, nor is "getSupportFragmentManager"

```
int errorCode = connectionResult.getErrorCode();
```

and

```
errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                    "Location Updates");
```

Should I just create a variable above called ConnectionResult connectionResult to fix the issue? I am not sure about how to correct the second.

Additionally, the line

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
```

from further along the page suggests putting in the MainActivity class which does not satisfy the LocationClient constructor, evoking another error.

**Update**: Another issue with the tutorial. Hi all, the tutorial references the class LocationResult which it has not created here: http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html. How/where am I supposed to define this?

Comment: your title is not related to your description

Comment: @juned thank you, i hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The tutorial is misleading. If you want to check google play services exist do the following.

```
int errorCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
if (errorCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
  GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(errorCode, this, 0).show();
}
```

This will automatically show an appropriate error dialog if it doesn't in exist.

To your second problem. The remainder of the tutorial does need to be followed. You do need to implement `GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks` and      `GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` if you want to create the the locationclient using `new LocationClient(this, this, this);`

Note: do not try to use the locationclient until after the `onConnected` method is called in your callback.

Answer (score -1):

Following the tutorial I ran into the same errors, however the code sample provided seems to be correctly implemented.

```
/**
 * Verify that Google Play services is available before making a request.
 *
 * @return true if Google Play services is available, otherwise false
 */
private boolean servicesConnected() {

    // Check that Google Play services is available
    int resultCode =
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    // If Google Play services is available
    if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == resultCode) {
        // In debug mode, log the status
        Log.d(LocationUtils.APPTAG, getString(R.string.play_services_available));

        // Continue
        return true;
    // Google Play services was not available for some reason
    } else {
        // Display an error dialog
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, 0);
        if (dialog != null) {
            ErrorDialogFragment errorFragment = new ErrorDialogFragment();
            errorFragment.setDialog(dialog);
            errorFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), LocationUtils.APPTAG);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/shareables/training/LocationUpdates.zip